# Sitecore 7:Avoid Duplicate selection in a Multilist

Tags: duplicates, sitecore, sitecore7

How can we avoid selection of an item twice in multilist sitecore?

Comment: The multilist field in Sitecore 7 does not allow for duplicate item selection. Am I missing something?

Comment: The MultiList with search-field does allow this. However, this is a bug and already reported to Sitecore.

Answer (score 1):

In your source for multilist filed make sure to set AllowMultipleSelection to no, for example:
/sitecore/content/Home/&AllowMultipleSelection=no

Comment: This works great for Multilist (the OP) but just as an FYI for everyone else, this does not work for Multilist with search (after a search you can still add a duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disallow selection of an item twice (however, this is a bug in the multilist-with-search-field), you can use a workaround by creating an item-save event which will check on duplicate values and throws a message when duplicates exist.

Comment: Do you know where the bug report for this is?  It still exists in V8 :-/

Answer (score 0):

he easiest way to add this constraint turned out to be adding a suitable validation regex on the intended field:

```
^{[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}\}$
```

You could add the intended message to the content author as well:
[image: 2014-10-27_015918]

Now, on save, the validation message will be triggered:
[image]